# Nodejs Twilio API 3.x - messages.delete(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, twilio-api

Was following [this tutorial to try and delete sms messages](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/redact-delete-sms-messages-node-js.html) and I can successfully retrieve an individual message via this code:

```
client.messages(sid).fetch()
  .then((message) => {
    console.log(message);
    if (message.status === "received") {
      client.messages(sid).delete() //failing here
        .then(() => {
          response.send('Message deleted');
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    }
  })
```

[The documentation example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/message#http-delete) only shows how to remove the message body, not delete the messgae itself. And when I console log `messages`, the only methods available are:

```
{ create: [Function: create],
  each: [Function: each],
  list: [Function: list],
  page: [Function: page],
  getPage: [Function: getPage],
  get: [Function: get] }
```

A note that I can successfully redact the message body, [following the instructions here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/message#redact-a-message):

```
client.messages(sid).update({body: ''})
.then((message) => {
    process.stdout.write(message.body);
    response.send('message deleted');
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the method you are looking for is `remove`. Modifying your code like below will actually remove the message:

```
client.messages(sid).fetch().then((m) => {
    if (m.status == "delivered") {
        console.log("It's delivered")
        console.log(m)
        m.remove().then(() => console.log("message removed"))
    }
})
```

You also need to take care of any media separately, as those are not deleted when deleting a message according to the documentation.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist and the original author of the blog post here. This is absolutely the right answer, I just wanted to explain that the post was written for version 2 of the [Twilio Node library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node) and you are now using version 3. I will endeavour to update the post so that this doesn't cause issues in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @philnash, and am I correct in understanding there is no way to remove a message via the Twilio console? Only through the API?

Comment: @mheavers [here](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/api-explorer/sms/messages/delete) you can find the delete functionality in the API explorer.